# I want to send a python's script output to a SSH shell

Tags: python, shell, terminal, raspberry-pi

Hello everyone I am making a car in Raspberry Pi-3. and I am sending some shh commands. my problem id that I do not want to send shh commands directly , although I want to send an output of a python console output how do i do so?

Comment: your question isn't clear, do you want to send the output (print statements etc) to an ssh shell or do you want the output of your python script to be treated as shell commands? if the first what is wrong with calling the script from the ssh session?

Comment: I want to treat the python console output as my input to SSH shell's input

Comment: really you have two options, you could span your ssh connection using `subprocess.Popen` and then send messages to that, or you could use a python ssh library such as http://www.paramiko.org/ either way you'll have to change your script so that the "output" is not printed but instead sent to either the subprocess or the ssh module

Comment: however for your intended purpose i would say that ssh is not the way to go. i would suggest that instead you look at implementing your own socket server that listens for your specific commands, as this would be more secure.

Comment: I am using putty on windows to connect my raspberry pi. I am making a car which will move forward while 'w' key is pressed. But unfortunately there is no such way in shh or terminal to tell that a keyboard key is released. So I will make a python program on windows via pyCharm or python IDLE(which suits better)  to send shh  text string of what is going  on and according to that my pi will decide what to do . Now tell me how to send text strings from python console to ssh on windows

Comment: i am not convinced this will work the way you intend, when you manually type into putty then putty can tell when a key is pressed/released, but by shelling out from python all you can do is send characters, so to "hold" the key down you would have to send the character many times, however if you send it too fast then it would "lag" and keep acting after you intend to stop that action. i seriously urge you to consider changing your architecture.

Comment: nope I am not sending a contnous stream of 'w' directly to ssh instead it will be send to my python script running in window and  when a key is pressed a string will be passes to ssh "W is pressed" and when I will release the 'w' a string "W is released" will  be passed to shh and than script running in raspbery pi will decide what to do based on recieved strings

Comment: Now please tell me how to integrate shh with python console

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OS library in python, which will allow the python program to integrate with the unix shell.

```
#Import Library
import os

#Set the action to 0 as it's not needed right now
action = 0

#Loop infinitely
while True:
    #First of all, list the available actions and let the user choose one.
    print('Actions that can be performed')
    print('ID.  Action')
    print('')
    print('1.  Go Forward')
    print('2.  Go Backwards')
    print('3.  Stop')
    print('')
    print('0.  Stop and exit program')
    print('')

    #Ask the 'driver' what they want the car to do. Program will hang continuing
    #to perform any current action that was previously selected until a different
    #action is provided.
    action = int(input('Enter the numerical ID of the action and press return: '))

    #Do the action based on the numerical ID
    if(action == 1):
        os.system('shell-command-to-go-forward')

    if(action == 2):
        os.system('shell-command-to-go-backward')

    if(action == 3):
        os.system('shell-command-to-stop-everything')

    if(action == 0):
        os.system('shell-command-to-stop-everything')
        exit(0)
```

If this is not what you are looking to do, please could you be more specific. Should the python script be taking any form of user input or not?

Answer (score 0):

i cannot help you with the ssh functionality you seek as i have never tried that nor do i have the tools available to me right now to try. however i don't believe that this is the right tool for the purpose.
instead i attach a socket server example with a tkinter GUI, pressing the arrow keys send events to the socket server which can then be acted upon.

## server.py:

```
import socket

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print('starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)

while True:
    try:
        # Listen for incoming connections
        sock.listen(1)

        while True:
            # Wait for a connection
            print('waiting for a connection')
            connection, client_address = sock.accept()

            try:
                print('connection from', client_address)

                # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
                while True:
                    data = connection.recv(16)
                    if data:
                        print('received "%s"' % data)
                        # here you can test the character received and act accordingly
                        # you could also opt to send data back the other way
#                       print('sending data back to the client')
#                       connection.sendall(data)
                    else:
                        print('no more data from', client_address)
                        break
                    
            finally:
                # Clean up the connection
                connection.close()
    except:
        pass
```

## client.py

```
import socket
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Car control")
        
        self.sock = None
        
        self.addr = tk.Entry(self)
        self.addr.insert(0, "127.0.0.1")
        self.addr.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Connect", command=self.connect)
        self.button.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        
        self.bind("<KeyPress>", self.handle_binding)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.handle_binding)
        
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.connect((self.addr.get(),10000))
            self.addr.configure(state="disabled")
            self.button.configure(text="Disconnect", command=self.disconnect)
            self.focus()
        except (ConnectionRefusedError, socket.gaierror):
            pass
        
    def disconnect(self):
        self.sock.close()
        self.sock = None
        self.addr.configure(state="normal")
        self.button.configure(text="Connect", command=self.connect)
        
    def send(self, data):
        if self.sock:
            self.sock.sendall(data.encode('utf8'))
            
    def handle_binding(self, event):
        if event.widget != self.addr: # ignore key events aimed at texkbox
            char = ""
            if event.keysym == "Up":
                char = "u"
            elif event.keysym == "Down":
                char = "d"
            elif event.keysym == "Left":
                char = "l"
            elif event.keysym == "Right":
                char = "r"
            if event.type == '2': # pressed
                self.send(char)
            elif event.type == '3': # released
                self.send(char.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```